# How do I uninstall ruby-runtime plugin from Jenkins running on Java 11

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

ruby-runtime is deprecated and fails to initialize when Jenkins is run on Java 11
The Jenkins Plugins UI does not have buttons to uninstall a plugin when it fails to initialize. This is causing garbage logs that I'd like to go away.
So, how do I properly manually uninstall a plugin like ruby-runtime?

I'm running Jenkins from an apt install on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: There is no solution yet - but you can follow the PR for the annoncement regarding non-java plugins deprecation here: https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/pull/4256

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to remove the plugin perform the following steps:

- stop jenkins
- go to your `JENKINS_HOME/plugins` folder and remove both the `ruby-runtime/` folder and the `ruby-runtime.jpi` file
- start jenkins